# How can I make my border-radius curve outward?

Tags: css, css-shapes

I am try to make a div have borders like the following drawing:

[image]

This is what I have tried:

```css
div {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:100px 10px;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

What is an effect way to accomplish this?

Comment: That is going to need some additional markup and not just border-radius.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

### Using [`:before` and `:after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements)

[image: Example]

#### The top border is created with the `:before`:

- Its height is the same as the border radius
- It is positioned just outside with `top` and lines up with the left border thanks to `left`
- Its width is calculated with `calc` to precisely line up the top of the curve
- The curve can be refined with `transform: skewX(-60deg)`

#### The left border is created with the `:after`:

- It is given a 100% height minus the height of the before and the thickness of the border with `calc`

### Examples

#### Number 1 - a bit pointy

```css
div {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 100px 20px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-top: none;
  height: 500px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  border-left: none;
}
div:before,
div:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: -1px;
}
div:before {
  height: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  width: calc(100% + 1px);
  border-bottom-right-radius: 100px 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  border-right: solid 1px #000;
  top: -1px;
}
div:after {
  height: calc(100% - 18px);
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
  top: 19px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

#### Number 2 - smoothed out point with skew

```css
div {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 100px 20px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-top: none;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  border-left: none;
}
div:before,
div:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: -1px;
}
div:before {
  height: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  width: calc(100% - 36px);
  border-bottom-right-radius: 100px 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  border-right: solid 2px #000;
  top: 0px;
  left: 17px;
  transform: skewX(-60deg);
}
div:after {
  height: calc(100% - 19px);
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
  top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is great, but why does the top border look so much sharper and pointing than the picture.

Comment: @user3741635 - its due to the way borders are drawn in CSS. Check out the example number 2 I just added to my answer - it's possible to smooth this out with `transform: skewX`

Comment: Just one more question, how could I change the color of the drawing from transparent to red for example.

Answer (score 8):

I could do it using DIVs, but I am pretty sure that exists a more elegant way to do it:

```css
    #container {
       border:none;   
       height:100px;
       border-right: solid 1px #000;
    }
    
    #square_top {
       border-bottom-right-radius:100px 10px;
       border:none;   
       border-bottom: solid 1px #000;
       height:10px;
    }
    
    #square_bottom {
       border-bottom-right-radius:100px 10px;
       border:none;   
       border-bottom: solid 1px #000;
       border-right:solid 1px #000;
       border-left:solid 1px #000;
       height:10px;
    }
    
    #square {
       height: 90px;
       border-left:solid 1px #000;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="container">
       <div id="square_top"></div>
       <div id="square">TEXT HERE</div>
    </div>   
    <div id="square_bottom"></div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Although CSS can do this, there is another approach that allows more flexibility : **SVG**

This approach allows :

- The shape addapts its size to the size of the content
- Responsive
- Allows any kind of background (image, gradients, semitransparent color...)
- Allows any kind of filling for the shape (image, gradients, semitransparent color...)
- easier to control the the top and bottom curves :

```css
body {background: url('http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-g-640-480-9.jpg');background-size: cover;}
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 30%;
  padding: 5%;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Some text</p>
  <p>Some text</p>
  <p>Some text</p>
  <p>Some text</p>
  <p>Some text</p>
  <p>Some text</p>
  <p>Some text</p>
  <p>Some text</p>
  <p>Some text</p>
  <svg viewbox="0 0 50 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <path d="M1 9 C49 10 49 1 49 1 V90 C49 91 49 99 1 99z"  stroke-width="0.5" stroke="#000" fill-opacity="0.5" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: I was going to add this, until i saw. people also need to use SVG

Comment: because it has not preserved aspect ratio, the shape changes. that's nice, but its causing the stroke-width of left and right strokes to change. Is there a way to overcome tat?

Comment: @TimKrul I wasn't aware of it before you asked but there is the `vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" ` attribute that allows to keep the width of the stroke fixed. But it does't seem to be supported by IE